# php+regex split into array by sections

Tags: php, regex, split

I need a help with php+regex split from input text file into array:
using preg_match_all

```
/(SUNDAY|MONDAY|TUESDAY|WEDNESDAY|THURSDAY|FRIDAY|SATURDAY)\R(\d{4})-([0-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])-([0-9]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\R(.*?)\R(.*?)\R\R/mi
```

day -> all day agenda, like this:

```
$x = array(
  '2017-03-21' => "9:00 Meeting\n12:00 Lunch",
  '2017-03-27' => "11:00 Meeting"
)
```

input file:

```
 some of text

 MONDAY
 2017-03-21
 9:00 Meeting
 12:00 Lunch

 FRIDAY
 2017-03-27
 11:00 Meeting

 END

 more text
```

Comment: share your tried code ?

Comment: You can split your text with `\n\n` and in each item, split it by `\n`, index 1 in earlier sub-split is your date , and others your `/` separated values!

Comment: is it necessary to check day NAME ? is there any other texts ?

Comment: use `preg_match_all` and `array_combine` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this regex:

```
(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\n(?<todos>[\s\S]*?)\n\n
```

You're capturing dates in 'date' (match[1]) group and other todo texts in 'todo'(match[2])

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/4Y6fsV/1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
\w+\n(?!\n)^(\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2})((\n\d+:\d+\s+\w+)+)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/n4x91E/5)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach(`preg_match_all` and `array_combine` functions):

```
$re = '/\b[A-Z]+\s(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{1,2})\s(.+?)(?=\n\n|$)/s';
$result = [];

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
if (isset($matches[1]) && isset($matches[2])) {
    $result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [2017-03-21] => 9:00 Meeting
12:00 Lunch
    [2017-03-27] => 11:00 Meeting
)
```